# Conectar API Shopify con c#

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando conectarme a la API de shopify con el siguiente código:

```
public static string GETShopify(string CallLoc, string APIKey, string Password, string StoreName)
        {
            string Str = APIKey + ":" + Password;
            byte[] byt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Str);
            Str = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byt);

            string Url = "https://" + StoreName + ".myshopify.com/admin/" + CallLoc;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);
            WebResponse response = null;

            NetworkCredential SimpleCredential = new NetworkCredential(APIKey, Password);
            request.Credentials = SimpleCredential;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Str);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
            }
            return response.ToString();

        }
```

El tema es que me devuelve un error 401 no autorizado, pero desconozco si es porque el código no es correcto o porque dispongo de una cuenta trial de 14 para trastear.

Alguien ha trabajado con la API de shopify y c# y decirme si ve algo erróneo en el código por favor?

Comment: Sugerencia: Has visto si tienen alguna API para pruebas?

Comment: No tiene API de pruebas. Puedes crear una web en modo dev si te das de alta con una cuenta de tipo Partner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de investigar más profundamente, he encontrado la solución.
El código fuente en sí es correcto.
El tema de shopify es que cree una cuenta de partner y desde alli, estaba creando la app a un site y tratando de vincularsela, cuando realmente esta operación se debe ejecutar desde el propio site.

Lo que quiere decir es que en el site origen de shopi, no en el portal de partners, si vas al apartado de Apps, ves las apps instaladas en el site. Yo lo que hacía era crear la APP en el portal de partner es intentar vincularla al site, pero lo que he hecho ha sido crear la APP desde el site principal y luego, darle permisos a la cuenta de Partner para editar/escribir en las distintas entidades. Hecho esto, conacta a la 1a.

Comment: Sería mucho pedir que por favor incluyas mayores detalles con lo que te refieres en: `esta operación se debe ejecutar desde el propio site.` Gracias :D

Comment: Edita la respuesta y agrega esa información, muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

De el manual de la API de Shopify te dice que si te devuelve 401 es porque el token expiro ni necesitas renovarlo.

> After an access token has expired, Shopify returns a 401 Unauthorized
> response code.

https://shopify.dev/api/usage/authentication

Para obtener el token esta toda una seccion dedicada a eso, es basicamente un Oauth, que peticionas a un endpoint establecido donde le pasas tus credenciales y te devuelve el token que debes utilizarlo y que tiene una caducidad.

Ahora para obtener tus credenciales (User  & secret) tenes que hacer un proceso de registrar tu app como se indica en el link mas abajo y seguir los pasos de acuerdo al tipo de App que vayas a registrar (que puede ser publica, privada, etc)

https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth#step-1-get-the-clients-credentials

Comment: Gracias, pero ya he repasado varias veces estos documentos. Dispongo tanto de la Key como de la Secreta. Al mismo tiempo, he seguido el paso de crear el enlace de instalación del comerciante. He activado la API en la configuración de la APP de shopify no consigo de ningún modo conectar satisfactoriamente :/